# How do I Pandas group-by to get sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I am using this dataframe:

```
Fruit   Date      Name  Number
Apples  10/6/2016 Bob    7
Apples  10/6/2016 Bob    8
Apples  10/6/2016 Mike   9
Apples  10/7/2016 Steve 10
Apples  10/7/2016 Bob    1
Oranges 10/7/2016 Bob    2
Oranges 10/6/2016 Tom   15
Oranges 10/6/2016 Mike  57
Oranges 10/6/2016 Bob   65
Oranges 10/7/2016 Tony   1
Grapes  10/7/2016 Bob    1
Grapes  10/7/2016 Tom   87
Grapes  10/7/2016 Bob   22
Grapes  10/7/2016 Bob   12
Grapes  10/7/2016 Tony  15
```

I would like to aggregate this by `Name` and then by `Fruit` to get a total number of `Fruit` per `Name`. For example:

```
Bob,Apples,16
```

I tried grouping by `Name` and `Fruit` but how do I get the total number of `Fruit`?

Comment: you can use dfsql  df.sql('SELECT fruit, sum(number) GROUP BY fruit')
https://github.com/mindsdb/dfsql

https://medium.com/riselab/why-every-data-scientist-using-pandas-needs-modin-bringing-sql-to-dataframes-3b216b29a7c0

Answer (score 444, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name']).sum()

Out[31]: 
               Number
Fruit   Name         
Apples  Bob        16
        Mike        9
        Steve      10
Grapes  Bob        35
        Tom        87
        Tony       15
Oranges Bob        67
        Mike       57
        Tom        15
        Tony        1
```

To specify the column to sum, use this: `df.groupby(['Name', 'Fruit'])['Number'].sum()`

Comment: The question is, if data is read from excel, and "Number" should be a string by default when we read data from excel, how to use sum() function?

Comment: ##there are five columns data in 'overview.csv' 

temp = pd.read_csv("overview.csv")
temp.groupby([temp.columns[0],temp.columns[1]])[temp.columns[4]].sum()

print(temp)

can not get the sum of 'temp.columns[4]'

Answer (score 265):

Also you can use agg function,

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Fruit'])['Number'].agg('sum')
```

Answer (score 209):

If you want to keep the original columns `Fruit` and `Name`, use `reset_index()`. Otherwise `Fruit` and `Name` will become part of the index.

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'])['Number'].sum().reset_index()

Fruit   Name       Number
Apples  Bob        16
Apples  Mike        9
Apples  Steve      10
Grapes  Bob        35
Grapes  Tom        87
Grapes  Tony       15
Oranges Bob        67
Oranges Mike       57
Oranges Tom        15
Oranges Tony        1
```

As seen in the other answers:

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'])['Number'].sum()

               Number
Fruit   Name         
Apples  Bob        16
        Mike        9
        Steve      10
Grapes  Bob        35
        Tom        87
        Tony       15
Oranges Bob        67
        Mike       57
        Tom        15
        Tony        1
```

Answer (score 68):

Both the other answers accomplish what you want.

You can use the `pivot` functionality to arrange the data in a nice table

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'],as_index = False).sum().pivot('Fruit','Name').fillna(0)



Name    Bob     Mike    Steve   Tom    Tony
Fruit                   
Apples  16.0    9.0     10.0    0.0     0.0
Grapes  35.0    0.0     0.0     87.0    15.0
Oranges 67.0    57.0    0.0     15.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 38):

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'])['Number'].sum()
```

You can select different columns to sum numbers.

Answer (score 25):

A variation on the .agg() function; provides the ability to (1) persist type DataFrame, (2) apply averages, counts, summations, etc. and (3) enables groupby on multiple columns while maintaining legibility.

```
df.groupby(['att1', 'att2']).agg({'att1': "count", 'att3': "sum",'att4': 'mean'})
```

using your values...

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Fruit']).agg({'Number': "sum"})
```

Answer (score 13):

You can set the `groupby` column to  `index`  then using `sum` with `level`

```
df.set_index(['Fruit','Name']).sum(level=[0,1])
Out[175]: 
               Number
Fruit   Name         
Apples  Bob        16
        Mike        9
        Steve      10
Oranges Bob        67
        Tom        15
        Mike       57
        Tony        1
Grapes  Bob        35
        Tom        87
        Tony       15
```

Answer (score 11):

You could also use [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) on column `Number` after group by. This operation will calculate the total number in one group with function `sum`, the result is a series with the same index as original dataframe.

```py
df['Number'] = df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'])['Number'].transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Fruit', 'Name']).drop('Date', 1)
```

Then, you can drop the duplicate rows on column `Fruit` and `Name`. Moreover, you can drop the column `Date` by specifying axis `1` (`0` for rows and `1` for columns).

```
# print(df)

      Fruit   Name  Number
0    Apples    Bob      16
2    Apples   Mike       9
3    Apples  Steve      10
5   Oranges    Bob      67
6   Oranges    Tom      15
7   Oranges   Mike      57
9   Oranges   Tony       1
10   Grapes    Bob      35
11   Grapes    Tom      87
14   Grapes   Tony      15

# You could achieve the same result with functions discussed by others: 
# print(df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'], as_index=False)['Number'].sum())
# print(df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'], as_index=False)['Number'].agg('sum'))
```

There is an official tutorial [Group by: split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) talking about what you can do after group by.

Comment: Hi Guys, your solution indeed work! my python version is 3.8, it seems that it did work if we only use sum().

Comment: @Rui Don't understand, you only say it works so when does it not work?

Comment: Ynjxsjmh, I mean if I just use 'df['Number'] = df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'])['Number'].transform('sum')', I can not get the sum of 'Number' grouped by 'Fruit', 'Name' pair. But, if I add the line as your comment suggested, df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Fruit', 'Name'])', then I got the sum expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the aggregated column to have a custom name such as `Total Number`, `Total` etc. (all the solutions on here results in a dataframe where the aggregate column is named `Number`), use named aggregation:

```py
df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'], as_index=False).agg(**{'Total Number': ('Number', 'sum')})
```

or (if the custom name doesn't need to have a white space in it):

```py
df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Name'], as_index=False).agg(Total=('Number', 'sum'))
```

this is equivalent to SQL query:

```sql
SELECT Fruit, Name, sum(Number) AS Total
FROM df 
GROUP BY Fruit, Name
```

Speaking of SQL, there's `pandasql` module that allows you to query pandas dataFrames in the local environment using SQL syntax. It's not part of Pandas, so will have to be installed separately.

```py
#! pip install pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
sqldf("""
SELECT Fruit, Name, sum(Number) AS Total
FROM df 
GROUP BY Fruit, Name
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dfsql
for your problem, it will look something like:

```
df.sql('SELECT fruit, sum(number) GROUP BY fruit')
```

https://github.com/mindsdb/dfsql

here is an article about it:

https://medium.com/riselab/why-every-data-scientist-using-pandas-needs-modin-bringing-sql-to-dataframes-3b216b29a7c0

Answer (score 1):

You can use reset_index() to reset the index after the sum

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'])['Number'].sum().reset_index()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['Fruit','Name'], as_index=False)['Number'].sum()
```