# Sum duplicate rows in two columns in Pandas dataframe by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, read into pandas from a csv.

```
           Fruit    Apple   Pear
Date                  
2016-03-30  Pear            1
2016-04-14  Pear            1
2016-04-14  Pear            1
2016-05-09  Apple   1
2016-05-18  Apple   1   
2016-06-24  Pear            1
2016-06-27  Apple   1   
2016-06-27  Pear            1
2016-06-28  Apple   1   
2016-06-28  Apple   1   
2016-07-05  Pear            1
```

I'd like it to look like this. It sums the duplicate rows and then drops the duplicate row. The value in the Fruit column doesn't matter at this point. I'll drop that column later.

```
           Fruit    Apple   Pear
Date                  
2016-03-30  Pear            1
2016-04-14  Pear            2
2016-05-09  Apple   1
2016-05-18  Apple   1   
2016-06-24  Pear            1
2016-06-27  Apple   1       1
2016-06-28  Apple   2   
2016-06-28  Apple   1   
2016-07-05  Pear            1
```

I tried using groupby, but it filled the Apple/Pear columns with 1s. I tried a for loop that if the next date index was the same as the current date index, it would += 1 to the respective Apple/Pear column. That failed because the type of the column, and my attempts to change the column type failed as well. Banging my head against this one and I can't get it.

The one thing I can do right is drop the duplicates with `df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('Date',keep='last').set_index('Date')`

Comment: Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to ask a good pandas question might be helpful.  Your posted frames are somewhat hard to parse, and it's not clear whether the value at 2016-03-30/Apple is a 0 or a NaN and you've suppressed it for some reason or an empty string, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index - `level=0` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df)
            Apple  Pear
Date                   
2016-03-30    NaN   1.0
2016-04-14    NaN   2.0
2016-05-09    1.0   NaN
2016-05-18    1.0   NaN
2016-06-24    NaN   1.0
2016-06-27    1.0   1.0
2016-06-28    2.0   NaN
2016-07-05    NaN   1.0
```

If need [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) as mentioned [`Noobie`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860963/sum-duplicate-rows-in-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-by-index/42861104?noredirect=1#comment72828418_42861104), thank you:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).cumsum() 
print (df)
            Apple  Pear
Date                   
2016-03-30    NaN   1.0
2016-04-14    NaN   1.0
2016-04-14    NaN   2.0
2016-05-09    1.0   NaN
2016-05-18    1.0   NaN
2016-06-24    NaN   1.0
2016-06-27    1.0   NaN
2016-06-27    NaN   1.0
2016-06-28    1.0   NaN
2016-06-28    2.0   NaN
2016-07-05    NaN   1.0
```

Comment: `df = df.groupby(level=0).sum().min().max().cumsum()` works as well

Comment: @Noobie - Thank you for suggestion, maybe you think something like `df.groupby(level=0).cumsum().reset_index().drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last')` ?

Comment: yes thats more efficient 

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Noobie's results in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cumsum'`

Comment: @jezrael's gives this `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. The df dtype is object. Is that the problem with trying to sum or cumsum them?

Comment: Yes, need cast to numeric by `df[['Apple', 'Pear']] = df[['Apple', 'Pear']].astype(float)` and if it does not work need to_numeric like `df['Apple'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Apple'], errors='coerce')` and then `df['Pear'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Pear'], errors='coerce')` for replace non numeric to Nan

Comment: `df['Apple'].apply(pd.to_numeric)` and to ['Pear'] seems to have fixed those errors. Chaining @jezrael's drop_duplicates gives a key error, but I can use the other drop dupe code. .sum works better than .cumsum for this. You can see on 2016-06-27, .cumsum left the dates split. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this

```
df.groupby(['Date','Fruit']).agg('sum')
```

I just realized it's a duplicate question, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum).