# how to sum values of column based on other column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like this :

```
ID  State  Qty
1   'UP'    2
1   'UP'    3
1   'AR'    1
2   'KJ'    3
4   'AP'    1
2   'KJ'    4
```

Here is what i need :

I want to sum the Qty values of multiple rows if both the values of ID and State columns are same for those rows and put them in a single row with the Qty value as sum .

So what I need is this :

```
ID  State  Qty
1   'UP'    5
1   'AR'    1
2   'KJ'    7
4   'AP'    1
```

How to do this efficiently ?

Comment: You use a groupby and sum. Just google it.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986

Comment: should i delete this question if its a duplicate ?

Comment: You can just leave it!

Comment: if it doesn't cause me downvotes i guess its ok to leave