# Grouping a running summary using pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python, spyder

I have a file full of data

Come up against an issue where i want to summarize results in a query.

Example being as follows:

```
NAME | FRUIT | PRICE 
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
```

This is my table at the moment, what i need though is to have a summary of Johns business, like below:

```
NAME | FRUIT      | PRICE 
JOHN | APPLE      |  2
JOHN | APPLE      |  2
JOHN | APPLE      |  2
JOHN | APPLE      |  2
JOHN | APPLETOTAL |  8 
JOHN | GRAPE      |  3
JOHN | GRAPETOTAL |  3
DAVE | GRAPE      |  3
DAVE | GRAPE      |  3
DAVE | GRAPE      |  3
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

1. Create a summary dataframe

   `summary_df = df.groupby(["NAME","FRUIT"] )["PRICE"].sum()`
2. Then mutate the FRUIT column like this

   `summary_df.FRUIT = summary_df.FRUIT.apply(lambda x : x + "TOTAL")`
3. Finally add the dataframe back to the base df

   `df = pd.concat([df, summary_df])`

You can sort this dataframe `df` by column FRUIT to get a sorted dataframe

Answer (score 1):

This should sort you out:

```
totals = df.groupby(['FRUIT', 'NAME']).sum().reset_index()
totals['FRUIT'] = totals['FRUIT'] + 'TOTAL'

result = pd.concat([df, totals]).sort_values(['NAME', 'FRUIT']).reset_index(drop=True)
result
#    NAME       FRUIT  PRICE
#0   DAVE       GRAPE      3
#1   DAVE       GRAPE      3
#2   DAVE       GRAPE      3
#3   DAVE  GRAPETOTAL      9
#4   JOHN       APPLE      2
#5   JOHN       APPLE      2
#6   JOHN       APPLE      2
#7   JOHN       APPLE      2
#8   JOHN  APPLETOTAL      8
#9   JOHN       GRAPE      3
#10  JOHN  GRAPETOTAL      3
```