# Annualised MEAN of returns.

Tags: python, pandas, calculation

Sorry am new to Pandas. Can I check how do I use Pandas to get the **annualized mean returns**. (Note: **NOT** the Annualized returns) I will like to calculate for the entire dataframe

> Mean of the returns: m = (1/M * Σ)

*M is the number of number of observations (1 date = 1 observation), 
r is the daily returns*

> Annualized daily mean returns = (1+m)^365 -1

I've already calculated the daily returns by using .pctchange

[image: This is the returns]

**So to give you guys an example, skipping the first column with NaN.**

From the second column assuming i made an observation from the 26th to 30th , therefore the calculation is:

m = (1/3 * (0.007246+0.001199+0.006587))= 0.00501

Annualized daily mean returns = (1+0.00501)^365 -1

*The formula is above*

Sorry for my poor english.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be useful to you. 
Assign datetime index, apply groupby function over year and calculate mean :-) 
[Groupby index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52218104/8208006)

Considered sample DataFrame

```
              TP    MENU    SLY     CZA
Time                
2016-01-31  1.01    -0.33   -0.60   0.0
2016-01-30  0.32    0.06    0.16    0.0
2017-01-29  -1.19   -0.10   0.34    0.0
2017-01-28  -0.31   0.62    -0.20   0.0
2017-01-27  0.39    0.03    -0.43   0.0
2017-01-26  1.21    -0.54   -0.21   0.0
2018-07-25  -0.39   0.67    -0.11   0.0
2018-07-24  -0.27   0.00    0.11    0.0
```

Code snippet

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby([df.index.year]).mean()
```

Output Annualised mean

```
          TP     MENU    SLY    CZA
2016    0.665   -0.1350 -0.220  0.0
2017    0.025   0.0025  -0.125  0.0
2018    -0.330  0.3350  0.000   0.0
```

Comment: Hi Naga, sorry to trouble you but do you have an example for the above example? thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide me the column names for that dataframe

Comment: the first column will be TP, 2nd column will be MENU, 3rd is SLY and 4th is CZA. Thanks a lot Naga! Appreciate it