# group id's according to their respective value in pandas panel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

In my panda panel I have two columns, 'id' and 'amount'. There are multiple transactions for the same id too. There can be positive and negative values in the 'amount'-column. Now, I want to group all id's where the amount is negative and count them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create boolean mask by compare by [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html) (`<`) and aggregate `sum` - `True` values are processes like `1`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c'],
    'amount': [-4,-5,6,7,1,-2,3,4,8]
})
print (df)
  id  amount
0  a      -4
1  a      -5
2  a       6
3  a       7
4  b       1
5  b      -2
6  b       3
7  c       4
8  c       8

df1 = df['amount'].lt(0).groupby(df['id']).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='count')
```

Or create index by `id` column and use `sum` only by `level=0` (index):

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')['amount'].lt(0).sum(level=0).astype(int).reset_index(name='count')
```

---

```
print (df1)
  id  count
0  a      2
1  b      1
2  c      0
```