# Groupby Rows and Sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(inventory_df)

dt_op        Prod_1  Prod_2 ... Prod_n
10/09/18       0        8         0
10/09/18       5        0         2

11/09/18       4        0         0
11/09/18       0       10         0

...

And I would like to get:

print(final_df)

dt_op        Prod_1  Prod_2 ... Prod_n
10/09/18       5        8         2     
11/09/18       4       10         0 

...
```

I tried with:

```
final_df = inventory_df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
```

But it does not produce the desired output. How can I create final_df?

Comment: do you want to drop all zeros from your dataframe even that they are assigned to different entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simulated the Stated  DataFrame, you asked about the `groupby` + `sum()`  across the  rows.

**Reproduced DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
      dt_op  Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_n
0  10/09/18       0       8       0
1  10/09/18       5       0       2
2  11/09/18       4       0       0
```

Using `groupby` around the columns `axis=1(of dimension 1, which is what used to be columns)` or simply `df.groupby('dt_op').sum` :

```
>>> df.groupby('dt_op').sum(axis=1)
          Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_n
dt_op
10/09/18       5       8       2
11/09/18       4       0       0
```

However, you are looking for the literal sum() of rows across the columns:

```
>>> df['new_sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
>>> df
      dt_op  Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_n  new_sum
0  10/09/18       0       8       0        8
1  10/09/18       5       0       2        7
2  11/09/18       4       0       0        4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` `groupby` function with `sum()`:

```
In [412]: inventory_df
Out[412]: 
      dt_op  Prod_1  Prod_2
0  10/09/18       0       8
1  10/09/18       5       0
2  11/09/18       4       0
3  11/09/18       0      10

In [413]: inventory_df.groupby('dt_op').sum()
Out[413]: 
          Prod_1  Prod_2
dt_op                   
10/09/18       5       8
11/09/18       4      10
```