# how to group the rows and sum the values in one column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tab separated file like this example:

small example:

```
chr5    112312630   112312650   31  chr5    112312630   112321662   DCP2    ENST00000543319.1
chr5    137676883   137676900   123 chr5    137676883   137676949   FAM53C  ENST00000434981.2
chr5    137676900   137676949   42  chr5    137676883   137676949   FAM53C  ENST00000434981.2
chr5    139944400   139944450   92  chr5    139944064   139946344   SLC35A4 ENST00000323146.3
chr5    139945450   139945500   77  chr5    139944064   139946344   SLC35A4 ENST00000323146.3
```

I want to group the lines based on `5th`, `6th` and `7th` columns and sum the values of `4th` column in each group. 
here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
chr5    112312630   112312650   31  chr5    112312630   112321662   DCP2    ENST00000543319.1
chr5    137676900   137676949   165 chr5    137676883   137676949   FAM53C  ENST00000434981.2
chr5    139944400   139944450   169 chr5    139944064   139946344   SLC35A4 ENST00000323146.3
```

I am trying to do that in python using the following command but it does not really work. do you know how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
df = df.groupby(5, 6, 7, 8).sum()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to group the cols:

```
df.groupby([5,6,7,8]).sum()
```

Comment: No, it aggregate all numeric columns by `sum` and OP need only `4.` column, but also is necessary not lost all another columns - check my solution

Comment: I put OP on the way ... After of course if can be tuned.

Answer (score 1):

You need aggregate by [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary of columns with aggregated functions, here all column different by `cols` are aggregate by [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), only `4` column is aggregated by `sum`:

```
cols = [5, 6, 7, 8]
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(cols), 'last')
d[3] = 'sum'
print (d)
{0: 'last', 1: 'last', 2: 'last', 3: 'sum', 4: 'last'}

df = df.groupby([5, 6, 7, 8], as_index=False).agg(d).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
      0          1          2    3     4          5          6        7  \
0  chr5  112312630  112312650   31  chr5  112312630  112321662     DCP2   
1  chr5  137676900  137676949  165  chr5  137676883  137676949   FAM53C   
2  chr5  139945450  139945500  169  chr5  139944064  139946344  SLC35A4   

                   8  
0  ENST00000543319.1  
1  ENST00000434981.2  
2  ENST00000323146.3
```

---

```
cols = [5, 6, 7, 8]
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(cols), 'first')
d[3] = 'sum'
print (d)
{0: 'first', 1: 'first', 2: 'first', 3: 'sum', 4: 'first'}

df = df.groupby([5, 6, 7, 8], as_index=False).agg(d).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
      0          1          2    3     4          5          6        7  \
0  chr5  112312630  112312650   31  chr5  112312630  112321662     DCP2   
1  chr5  137676883  137676900  165  chr5  137676883  137676949   FAM53C   
2  chr5  139944400  139944450  169  chr5  139944064  139946344  SLC35A4   

                   8  
0  ENST00000543319.1  
1  ENST00000434981.2  
2  ENST00000323146.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['column'])[['another column']].sum()
```

It groups by `column` and add sum of `another column`.
I used `[]` so that you understand you can group by multiple columns, like this:

```
df.groupby(['column1', 'column2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Input Dataframe: considering only first 3 rows,

```
data = {'col1': ['chr5', 'chr5', 'chr5'],
        'col2': [112312630,137676883,137676900],
        'col3': [112312650,137676900,137676949],
        'col4': [31, 123,42],
        'col5': ['chr5', 'chr5', 'chr5'],
        'col6': [112312630 ,137676883 ,137676883 ],
        'col7': [112321662, 137676949, 137676949],
        'col8': ['DCP2', 'FAM53C', 'FAM53C'],
       'col9': ['ENST00000543319.1', 'ENST00000434981.2', 'ENST00000434981.2']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df
```

Do like this,

```
cols = ['col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8']
col_sum = df.groupby(cols)['col4'].sum()
col_sum
```

Output: this is a multi-level dataframe. Last column is your output,

```
col5  col6       col7       col8  
chr5  112312630  112321662  DCP2       31
      137676883  137676949  FAM53C    165
```

Comment: this returns : 2994450    2994675    RHNO1          ENST00000461997.2                                                chr12
7155218    7155278    CTDNEP1        ENST00000318988.6                                           chr17chr17
9286722    9286821    DENND5A        ENST00000328194.3                                                chr11

Comment: @user10657934 provide your dataset file so I can resolve that issue.

Comment: the example in the question is exactly a part of my file

Comment: @user10657934 let me make dataframe from this and will give you a code example in a while.

Comment: @user10657934 `char5` is a data column or index?

Comment: @user10657934 Have a look on updated answer. let me know if this worked well for you.