# Pandas dataframe: specific intervals in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run a for loop with specific intervals.
It's a big data file and I need the cumulative sum to a **specific number** of every single product.
In the last column I can see when a new Product starts.

For example:

Specific sum for second Product, 7: 6.1 + 1.0 > 7 --> mark this row (1.0) and jump to the next Product with Change '1'.

```
for i in range (0, 3):
    ....
    ....


DATE         PRODUCT        PRICE   Change
01.01.2017   NEG_00_12       2.0      0
01.01.2017   NEG_00_12       8.9      0
01.01.2017   NEG_12_24       6.1      1
01.01.2017   NEG_12_24       1.0      0
01.01.2017   NEG_12_24       2.3      0
02.01.2017   NEG_00_12       4.1      1
02.01.2017   NEG_00_12       5.0      0
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You could improve your question by showing what you tried and why that didn't match the expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: Sry, but I need to be able to sum up to a specific number, for example:

Price1: 7

Therefor 6.1 + 1.0 > 7 --> mark this row (1.0) and jump to the next Product with Change '1'.

Comment: val = pd.Index(df.PRICE.cumsum()).get_loc(7, 'backfill')
Price_maxmin = df.get_value(val, 'CAPACITY')

So I get the value of another column of the row with cumsum >7

Answer (score 0):

if 'df' is the variable to which your data frame is assigned:

```
df1 = df.groupby('PRODUCT').sum()

df1.reset_index(drop=True)

for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    print("Price {}: {}".format(idx, row.PRODUCT)
```

Comment: It says 'DataFrame' object is not callable (df1).

I added a new column, when it says '1' a new loop needs to begin, but how can i do this?