# Pandas: How to sum a variable by group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to sum multiple values to one in python.
See the picture below of my data. I want to sum all the values of `AGE` for each year for each country.

Instead of having this:

```
country  TIME       AGE      Value
A        2017       20-60     200
A        2017       60-80     100
A        2016       20-60     200
A        2016       60-80     200
B        2017       20-60     300
B        2017       60-80     300
B        2016       20-60     400
B        2016       60-80     400
```

I would like to have this:

```
country  TIME             Value
A       2017               300       
A       2016               400
B       2017               600       
B       2016               800
```

The types of data:

```
df4types
AGE      object
Value    object
dtype: object
```

The data has a multi index by country and `TIME`.

If have tried this:

```
df=df.groupby(by=["TIME","GEO"])['Value'].sum()
```

and this:

```
df=df.groupby(by=["TIME","GEO"]).sum()['Value']
```

Both "worked" but result in an enormous value. Like it doesn't sum but paste the numbers behind each other. I have tried to change the variable type to numeric by using:
by `df.Value.astype(float) &  df.Value.astype(int)`

Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. Does someone have an idea how to sum the values by group and time correctly? I have also uploaded a picture of the real dataset.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum

Comment: `df.Value = df.Value.astype(int)` then run your code again

Comment: You have strings and not numbers. When you `sum`, you concatenate the strings. Notice that you have to *assign back* the result of `df.Value.astype(int)`

Comment: What is GEO is groupby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The age column doesn't seem to play a role in the data you want.
- The "Value" shouldn't be a dtype=object.  If you try `df.Value = df.Value.astype(int)` or `df.Value=pd.to_numeric(df.Value)` and it doesn't work then I'm betting there is some data you will need to clean up in that column)
- You shouldn't need to mess with the multi index

After you do the above then try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(<your data here>)
result = df.groupby(by=['country','TIME']).sum()
```