# Python (3.7) CSV Sort/Sum by Field Value

Tags: python

I have a `csv` file (of indefinite size) that I would like to read and do some work with.
Here is the structure of the `csv` file:

```
User, Value
CN,500.00
CN,-250.00
CN,360.00
PT,200.00
PT,230.00
...
```

**I would like to read the file and get the sum of each row where the first field is the same.**
I have been trying the following just to try and identify a value for the first field:

```
with open("Data.csv", newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        if row.startswith('CN'):
            print("heres one")
```

This fails because `startswith` does not work on a list object. I have also tried using `readlines()`.

**EDIT 1:**

I can currently print the following dataframe object with the sorted sums:

```
         Value
User
CN    3587881.89
D        1000.00
KC    1767783.99
REC     12000.00
SB      25000.00
SC    1443039.12
SS          0.00
T     9966998.93
TH    2640009.32
ls        500.00
```

I get this output using this code:

```
mydata=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
out = mydata.groupby(['user']).sum()
print(out)
```

Id now like be able to write if statements for this object. Something like:

```
if out contains User 'CN'
    varX = Value for 'CN'
```

because this is now a dataframe type I am having trouble setting the Value to a variable for a specific user.

Comment: Have you tried using pandas?

Comment: @yatu I have not looked into that as an option yet, but I will now

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data= pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
my_data.group_by('user').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use first row element:

```py
import csv

with open("Data.csv", newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0].startswith('CN'):
            print("heres one")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict 

result = defaultdict(int)
with open(filename, newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        result[row[0]] += float(row[1])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'CN': 610.0, 'PT': 430.0})
```