# How do I calculate the mean of one column according to a value in a second column?

Tags: python, dataframe, average

I have 2 columns in a DataFrame and I am looking for following solution in Python.

My Dataframe looks currently like this:

```
columns: INDUSTRY         Revenue
         Service          100
         Manufacturing    50
         Service          200
         Manufacturing    100
         Public           60
```

What I would like to have is the average per INDUSTRY type in a DataFrame:

```
columns: INDUSTRY         Revenue
         Service          150
         Manufacturing    75
         Public           60
```

I know how to do this in R with the function table, but I just started with python. Thank you

Comment: your code is required

Comment: Use `.groupby()`

Answer (score 2):

In python it is called groupby, as your dataframe is called Industry you have to use:

`Industry.groupby('Industry')['Revenue'].mean()`

on stackoverflow there are several examples about it: [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum/39923815)

Comment: Thanks, it work. If I want to transform the groupby into a DataFrame: pd.DataFrame(Industry), What happen is that the columns are not on the same level on the first row. The column name Industry starts in row 2. How can I solve that?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean, but get it back in a dataframe: `df2 = Industry.gorupby('Industry')['Revenue'].mean().reset_index()`should help you