# After Grouping ..Sum of a column values based on the groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

After grouping the column of the pandas dataframe how to do sum of another column of a dataframe based on the groups created.

`df = df.groupby(by=['First'])`

My dataframe:

```
First  Second

A      5
       6
       10
B      4
       5
```

expected dataframe:

```
First  Second

A      21
B      9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: `df.groupby('First').sum()`

Comment: How to do sum after grouping the column?

Comment: Can you add df.to_dict() to this question?  You input dataframe printed here is ambiguous.

Comment: I have 0.24 version of pandas

Comment: I have 63 columns in a data frame

Comment: Is First level=0 in the index?

Comment: Not equal to 0 in the index

Comment: `'A'` of `First` corresponding to `5, 6, 10` in column `Second`, so its sum value of `Second` must be `21`. Why your output shows it as `11` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
df= df.groupby(['First'])['Second'].sum().reset_index()
```

I noticed you are missing a ' in your code, it might have been causing you issues before.