# How can I do a calculation depending on a condition in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I would like to make a calculation when there is a group of ones that follow continuously.

I have a database on how a compressor works. Every 5 minutes I get the compressor status if it is ON/OFF and the electricity consumed at this moment. The column `On_Off` there are a `1` when the compressor works (ON) and  `0` when it is OFF.

```
Compresor = pd.Series([0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0], index = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=18, freq='5 min'))
df = pd.DataFrame(Compresor)
df.index.rename("Date", inplace=True)
df.set_axis(["ON_OFF"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.loc[(df.ON_OFF == 1), 'Electricity'] = np.random.randint(4, 20, df.sum())
df.loc[(df.ON_OFF < 1), 'Electricity'] = 0
df


                             ON_OFF     Electricity
      Date              
      2012-01-01 00:00:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 00:05:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 00:10:00       1       4.0
      2012-01-01 00:15:00       1       10.0
      2012-01-01 00:20:00       1       9.0
      2012-01-01 00:25:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 00:30:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 00:35:00       1       17.0
      2012-01-01 00:40:00       1       10.0
      2012-01-01 00:45:00       1       5.0
      2012-01-01 00:50:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 00:55:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 01:00:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 01:05:00       0       0.0
      2012-01-01 01:10:00       1       14.0
      2012-01-01 01:15:00       1       5.0
      2012-01-01 01:20:00       1       19.0
      2012-01-01 01:25:00       0       0.0
```

What I would like to do is to add the electrical consumption only when there is a set of ones and make another `Data.Frame`. For example:

[image]

In this example, the first time that the compressor was turned on was between 00:20 -00:30. During this period it consumed 25 (10+10+5). The second time it lasted longer on (00:50-01:15) and consumed in this interval 50 (10+10+10+10+10+5+5). The third time it consume 20 (10 + 10).

I would like to do this automatically  I'm new to pandas and I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: Rather than providing input data as a picture, please look at [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a sample input and output in the text of your question so that we can help you better

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have the following data:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd
import pandas as pd
from funcy import concat, repeat
from toolz import partitionby

base_data = {
    'time': list(range(20)),
    'state': list(concat(repeat(0, 3), repeat(1, 4), repeat(0, 5), repeat(1, 6), repeat(0, 2))),
    'value': list(concat(repeat(0, 3), rnd.randint(5, 20, 4), repeat(0, 5), rnd.randint(5, 20, 6), repeat(0, 2)))
}
```

Well, there are two ways:

The first one is functional and independent of `pandas`: you simply `partition` your data by a field, i.e. the method is processes the data sequentially and generates a new partition every time the value of the field changes. You can then simply summarize each partition as desired.

```
# transform into sample data
sample_data = [dict(zip(base_data.keys(), x)) for x in zip(*base_data.values())]
# and compute statistics the functional way
[sum(x['value'] for x in part if x['state'] == 1)
 for part in partitionby(itemgetter('state'), sample_data)
 if part[0]['state'] == 1]
```

There is also the `pandas` way, similarly to what @ivallesp mentioned:
You compute the change of state by shifting the state column. Then you [summarize your data frame by the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

```
pd_data = pd.DataFrame(base_data)
pd_data['shifted_state'] = pd_data['state'].shift(fill_value = pd_data['state'][0])
pd_data['cum_state'] = np.cumsum(pd_data['state'] != pd_data['shifted_state'])
pd_data[pd_data['state'] == 1].groupby('cum_state').sum()
```

Depending on what you *and your peers* can read best you can choose your way. Also, the functional way may not be easily readable, and can also rewritten with readable loop statments.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is creating a variable representing each period of activity with an integer as an ID, then group by it and sum the `Electricity` column. An easy way of creating it would be by cumulative summing `On_Off` (the data has to be sorted by increasing date) and multiplying the resulting value by the `On_Off` column. If you provide a reproducible example of your table in Pandas I can quickly write you the solution.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks @ivallesp. I put reproducible example of my table in Pandas in the question description.