# How to replicate an SQL groupby query with summing of columns based on conditions using Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to replicate the following SQL code using Pandas functions. This SQL code block contains a groupby and summation of columns based on different conditions.

I tried using pandas groupby and apply functions but couldn't crack the logic.

```
select id, lcode,
sum(case when type='A' and code='$' AND sub_code='B' then
amount else 0 end) as A_amount,
sum(case when type='P' and code='$' AND sub_code='B' then
amount else 0 end) as P_amount,
sum(case when type='W' and code='$' AND sub_code='B' then
amount else 0 end) as W_amount
from TRANSACTIONS
where id in ('1235','2456','4231','2341','9624')
GROUP BY id, lcode
```

The requirement is to replicate this logic in Python using Pandas functions.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763038/11610186

Comment: Can you add some sample data ?

Comment: What does your pandas' dataframe look like, and are the 'id', 'code', 'sub_code' fields already filtered?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski That solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @VikasP It's some confidential data. Skibinski's answer helped. Thanks!