# Pandas merge column duplicate and sum value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in pandas df:

```
quantity    color

1           White
3           White
1           Black
2           Black
```

I need to group duplicates and get the sum of their quantities:

```
quantity    color

4           White
3           Black
```

I have tried the following code to first sort by quantity, then using groupby to combine duplicates and get the sum.

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['quantity','color'], ascending=False)
df2 = df1.groupby(['color']).sum()
print(df2)
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
White    13
Black    12
```

As you can see it's not giving me the sum of the quantity, it's just listing those values side by side in the next column (1,3) and (1,2) for each color.

Comment: Check the `dtype` of `quantity` column and change it to `int`, using `df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].astype(int)`.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa: good observation. Its just joining string values :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: I'm getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" when using .astype(int)

Comment: Use `df['quanity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['quantity'])` And then use your `groupby` method. That should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there must be empty spaces in the example you are giving and that's the reason for why `astype(int)` isn't working. Using `pd.to_numeric` and passing `errors='coerce'` will make sure we convert all string values to `np.Nan` which can be easily dealt with when using `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'quantity':[1,3,1,2],'color':['White','White','Black','Black']}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df['quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['quantity'],errors='coerce')
print(df.groupby('color')['quantity'].sum())
```

Output:

```
color
Black    3
White    4
```

Comment: No, just two columns (quantity, color).

Comment: I mean in the `quantity` column, are other values? Did you tried `.str.replace(' ', '').astype(int)`? if it's not working, what error are you getting? Could there values that have `commas` ?

Comment: There are no other values other than numbers in the quantity column. Yes, I tried the replace blank spaces code, but still getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quantity'"

Comment: How about we use `astype('float64')`? Edited in answer too.

Comment: I just looked again at the csv i'm reading. Only thing in the quantity column are numbers 1, 2, 3, 4. No weird characters or anything.

Comment: It's trying to pass (float64) as a variable. Not defined.

Comment: Sorry meant between apostrophes. astype('float64')

Comment: Is it possible that your csv contains empty values in the column `quantity`?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'quantity'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200530/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-bronson77).