# Calculation according to column Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001], "Name": ["Alice", "Ana", "Tom", "John", "Frank", "Alice"], "Count":[20, 500, 1000, 30, 50, 66]})`

and how can I calculate how many children were born in each year ? for instance according to data frame above in 2000 year we had 20+500+1000 means 1520 new children.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
my_final = df.groupby("Year")["Count"].sum()

print(my_final)
```

This will calculate the number of children per year.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, and how can I check in which year was the biggest numer of new children ?

Comment: `df.groupby("Year")["Count"].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)` the top result is the one with the largest number.

Comment: Perfect, and the last question If you have a second, how can I show on the plot for instance top 5 years with the biggest numer of new children using for instance bar graph ?

Comment: It is best first if you try by yourself. Check: matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate the new children in the year 2000:

```
df[df["Year"]==2000]["Count"].sum()
```

Comment: This only computes one year instead of each year group. On top of that, using chained indexing is a poor choice.

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest number of children try following(as per OP's comments in comment section of 1 of the answers). This will give year in which highest number of children were born.

```
df.groupby('Year').agg({'Count': 'sum'}).reset_index().max()
```