# Cumulative sum of all previous values

Tags: python, pandas, sum

A similar question has been asked for `cumsum` and `grouping` but it didn't solve my case.

I have a financial balance sheet of a lot of years and need to sum all previous values by year.

This is my reproducible set:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
{"Amount": [265.95,2250.00,-260.00,-2255.95,120],
"Year": [2018,2018,2018,2019,2019]})
```

The result I want is the following:

```
Year  Amount
2017  0
2018  2255.95
2019  120.00
2020  120.00
```

So actually in a loop going from the lowest year in my whole set to the highest year in my set.

```
...
df[df.Year<=2017].Amount.sum()
df[df.Year<=2018].Amount.sum()
df[df.Year<=2019].Amount.sum()
df[df.Year<=2020].Amount.sum()
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is aggregate `sum`, then use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with forward filling missing values by all possible years, last replace first missing values to `0`:

```
years = range(2017, 2021)
df1 = (df.groupby('Year')['Amount']
         .sum()
         .cumsum()
         .reindex(years, method='ffill')
         .fillna(0)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Year   Amount
0  2017     0.00
1  2018  2255.95
2  2019   120.00
3  2020   120.00
```

Comment: Great answer @jezrael ! Thanks a lot, you shared valuable insights in the use of sequences in functions as well ;-) Grazie Mille !