# Pandas sort by subtotal of each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Still new into pandas but is there a way to sort df by subtotal of each group.

```
 Area   Unit   Count
  A     A1      5
  A     A2      2
  B     B1      10
  B     B2      1 
  B     B3      3
  C     C1      10
```

So I want to sort them by subtotal of each `Area` which results to `A subtotal = 7, B subtotal=14, C subtotal = 10`
The sort should be like

```
 Area   Unit   Count
  B     B1      10
  B     B2      1 
  B     B3      3
  C     C1      10
  A     A1      5
  A     A2      2
```

*Note that despite the value of `B3 > B1` it should not be affected by the sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: It is slightly different as I needed to sort them just by the group that has a higher value. Thanks anyway the answer is below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a helper column 'sorter', which is the sum of the count variable, and sort ur dataframe with it

```
df['sorter'] = df.groupby("Area").Count.transform('sum')

df.sort_values('sorter',ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).drop('sorter',axis=1)


  Area  Unit    Count
0   B   B1       10
1   B   B2      1
2   B   B3      3
3   C   C1      10
4   A   A1      5
5   A   A2      2
```

Comment: Didn't thought of this trick at all. Haha Thank you so much! It solved my problem.