# How to use groupby to get sum of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
     Location    Month    Unit

0    Loc1        1        5

1    Loc1        1        5 

2    Loc1        2        6

3    Loc2        2        6 

4    Loc2        3        7

5    Loc2        3        7
```

I figured I could use groupby to get the following output:

```
     Location    Month    Unit

0    Loc1        1        10

1    Loc1        2        6

2    Loc2        2        6

3    Loc2        3        14
```

However, I have not figured out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Location', 'Month'], as_index=False)['Unit'].sum()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you, that answers my question.