# Data grouping over two columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like:

[Origional Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7FQJ.png)

I would like to regroup the dataframe to be:

[New Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyLMh.png)

Can I do that using pd.groupby() or any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)  and [`Groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
print(df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    A    B    10
1    C    D    15
2    B    A    15
3    D    C     3
```

---

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
new_df = (df.assign(**dict(zip(cols, np.sort(df[cols], axis=1).T)))
            .groupby(cols, as_index=False).sum())
print(new_df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    A    B    25
1    C    D    18
```

Or

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2[cols] = np.sort(df[cols], axis=1)
df2.groupby(cols, as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: Can you pls show what the second line (df2[cols] = np.sort(df[cols], axis=1)                          ) exactly did?