# Pandas Dataframe: Binning in Multiple Dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe, df, consisting of a class of two objects, `S`, a set of co-ordinates associated with them, `X` and `Y`, and a value, `V`, that was measured there.

For example, the dataframe looks like this:

```
S X Y V
0 3 3 1
0 4 3 2
1 6 0 1
1 3 3 8
```

I would like to know the commands that allow me to group the `X` and `Y` coordinates associated with the class, `S` in a new binning. In this new picture, the new value of `V` should be the sum of the values in the bin for each class, `S`.

For example, suppose this co-ordinate system was initially binned between 0 and 10 in `X` and `Y` respectively. I would like to bin it between 0 and 2. This means:

- Values from `0 < X <= 5`, `0 < Y <= 5` in the old binning constitute the value 0;
- Values from `6 < x <= 10`, `6 < y <= 10` in the old binning constitute the value 1;

Edit:

For further example, considering Dataframe `df`:

1. Row 1 has `X = 3` and `Y = 3`. Since `0 < X <= 5` and `0 < Y <= 5`, this falls into bin `(0,0)`
2. Row 2 has `X = 4` and `Y = 3`. Since `0 < X <= 5` and `0 < Y <= 5`, this also falls into bin `(0,0)`.
3. Since Row 1 and 2 are observed in the same bin and are of the same class `S`, they are added along column `V`. This gives a combined row, `X=0, Y=0, V = 1+2 =3`
4. Row 3 has  has `X = 6` and `Y = 0`. Since `6 < X <= 10` and `0 < Y <= 5`, this falls into bin `(1,0)`
5. Row 4 has  has `X= 3` and `Y = 3`. Since `0 < X <= 5` and `0 < Y <= 5`, this falls into bin `(0,0)`. However, since the element is of class `S=1`, It is not added to anything, since we only add between shared classes.

The output should then be:

```
S X Y V
0 0 0 3
0 1 0 1
1 0 0 8
```

What commands must I use to achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain a bit better how the output is obtained from your input df?

Comment: Edited to include the logical process,

Comment: Thanks, now it is indeed more clear how columns X,Y and V are updated. I am still missing the role of column S in all this though

Comment: Edited to include the effect of the class column, 'S'

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
data.loc[data['X'] <= 5, 'X'] = 0
data.loc[data['X'] > 5, 'X'] = 1
data.loc[data['Y'] <= 5, 'Y'] = 0
data.loc[data['Y'] > 5, 'Y'] = 1

data = data.groupby(['S', 'X', 'Y']).sum().reset_index()
```

For your example the output is:

```
   S  X  Y  V
0  0  0  0  3
1  1  0  0  8
2  1  1  0  1
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923012/12182316) to be helpful.