# Python Pandas Group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've the below code

```
import pandas as pd

Orders = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\Bharath Shana\Desktop\Python\Sample.xls", sheet_name='Orders')

Returns = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\Bharath Shana\Desktop\Python\Sample.xls", sheet_name='Returns')

Sum_value = pd.DataFrame(Orders['Sales']).sum

Orders_Year = pd.DatetimeIndex(Orders['Order Date']).year

Orders.merge(Returns, how="inner", on="Order ID")
```

which gives the output as below

[image]

My Requirement is i would like to use **groupby** and would like to see the output as below

[image]

Can some one please help me how to use **groupby** in my above code, it means i would like to see everything in the single line by using **groupby**

Regards,

Bharath

Comment: ``df.groupby(['Year', 'Segment'])['Sales'].sum()`` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: I've modified you code as `Orders.groupby(['Year', 'Segment'])['Sales'].sum()` but inner join is not working if I use this. It is showing all the values instead of matching values.

Comment: what don you mean by all values and matching values?

Comment: I’m using two sheets ‘Orders’ and ‘Returns’ and if i do inner join i only get the matching records from both the sheets. Instead of showing the matching records it is showing all the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by selecting column then define to a new dataframe

```
grouped = pd.DataFrame()
groupby = ['Year','Segment','Sales']

for i in groupby:
    grouped[i] = Orders[i]
```