# How to Use different aggregate function for different Series -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this data-frame
and changes that i want with the data-frame's series are mentioned within the  brackets :

```
date(first case)    project_name(use distinct name)   billed_amount(apply sum)
16-aug                     project-1                           500
16-aug                     project-1                           100
17-aug                     project-2                           1000
17-aug                     project-2                           100
```

I want new Data-frame to be like below

```
date    project_name   billed_amount
16-aug    project-1     600
17-aug    project-2     1100
```

Is this Possible with Pandas??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score -1):

Group by *date* and *project_name*, then do a sum over *billed_amount*

```
df.groupby(['date','project_name'])['billed_amount'].sum()
```

Comment: yeah this does work but how can i save the result to new dataframe.