# Aggregate column in dataframe by values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
         location_id  ...  partner_code     product_code  value
24275            239  ...           AUT             8412      0
24496            239  ...           CHN             8412   1000
24742            239  ...           DEU             8412  20000
24831            239  ...           DNK             8412   4000
25094            239  ...           FRA             8412      0
...              ...  ...           ...              ...    ...
3490121          239  ...           KOR             2503   3000
3490152          239  ...           MYS             2503  15000
3490398          239  ...           CAN             2503      0
3490519          239  ...           IND             2503      0
3490597          239  ...           SGP             2503    350
```

I want to aggregate the values of the `value` column by the `product_code` values, so that for each product code, there is just one value that is a sum of values across all partners, which should look like this:

```
         location_id  ...  partner_code     product_code  value
n                239  ...           ALL             8412  25000
...              ...  ...           ...              ...    ...
n                239  ...           ALL             2503  18350
```

I tried using something like: `filtered_data = data.groupby('product_code').agg('value')`, which creates an uncallable groupby object.

How can I modify this code to perform the desired aggregation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: After aggregation, all the data in the `partner_code` column become `ALL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do with other columns, but this should solve your query

```
data.groupby('product_code')['value'].sum()
```