# Count values in columns with specific column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
Subs_1718   Count_1718  Subs_1819   Count_1819  Subs_1920   Count_1920
Apple           10.0      Grapes         12       Banana       12.0
Grapes           2.0      Apple           6       Grapes        8.0
Banana           2.0      Pineapple       3       Cashew        1.0
Dragonfruit      1.0      Banana          2       Apple         1.0
Kiwi             1.0      Kiwi            2       Melon         1.0
Melon            1.0      Cashew          1       Grapes        1.0
```

How do I create a new column that value_counts the values of the columns of `df['Count_1718']`,
`df['Count_1819']`,`df['Count_1920']`?

Expected Output:

```
Subs_1720         Count_1720
Apple              17
Banana             16
Cashew              2
Dragonfruit         1
Grapes             22
Melon               2 
Pineapple           1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) here specifying the corresponding stubnames with a [`groupby.sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum):

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                 stubnames=['Subs', 'Count'], 
                 i='index', j='ix', 
                 suffix= '_\d+')
   .groupby('Subs').sum())

             Count
Subs              
Apple         17.0
Banana        16.0
Cashew         2.0
Dragonfruit    1.0
Grapes        23.0
Kiwi           3.0
Melon          2.0
Pineapple      3.0
```

Comment: sorry, I'll take the one that posts first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. I do think the `suffix` arg here `'_\d+'` simplifies it quite a bit, but your call :) @Luc

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                    i='index', 
                    stubnames=['Subs','Count'], 
                    sep='_', 
                    j='d')
       .groupby('Subs')['Count']
       .sum()
       .rename_axis('Subs_1720')
       .reset_index(name='Count_1720'))
print (df1)
     Subs_1720  Count_1720
0        Apple        17.0
1       Banana        16.0
2       Cashew         2.0
3  Dragonfruit         1.0
4       Grapes        23.0
5         Kiwi         3.0
6        Melon         2.0
7    Pineapple         3.0
```

Comment: ha, same thought there :D

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the columns to a multiindex, stack, and do a groupby :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
(df.stack()
.groupby("Subs")
.sum()
.reset_index()
.set_axis(["Subs_1720", "Count_1720"], axis=1))

    Subs_1720   Count_1720
0   Apple       17.0
1   Banana      16.0
2   Cashew      2.0
3   Dragonfruit 1.0
4   Grapes      23.0
5   Kiwi        3.0
6   Melon       2.0
7   Pineapple   3.0
```

Comment: sorry, I'll take the one that posts first. Thanks a lot!