# Regarding handling duplicates & summing certain column values in a pandas data frame-

Tags: python, pandas, sum, multiple-columns

I want to sum the C & D columns  before removing the first duplicate value

For Example

```
Index     ID        A       B         C        D

0         AA       100      2         4        6

1         AA       200      3         5        4

2         BB        50      1         2        3

3         BB       300      4         1        0
```

Before removing the duplicates I want to sum the C & D columns and then remove the duplicates as shown below

```
Index     ID        A       B         C        D

1         AA       200      3         9        10

3         BB       300      4         3        3
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to `transform` first (i.e. broadcast the sum back to columns C and D), and just then drop the `duplicated`

```
df[['C', 'D']] = df.groupby('ID')[['C', 'D']].transform('sum')
df.loc[df.duplicated('ID')]
```

---

```
   Index  ID    A  B  C   D
1      1  AA  200  3  9  10
3      3  BB  300  4  3   3
```

Comment: Rafael, Thanks a lot for your help. I will try this code.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregate groupby:

```
 df.groupby("ID").agg({'A':'last', 'B':'last','C':'sum','D':'sum'})
```