# PANDAS: Sum value of column grouped by other column in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

First I am sorry if this is a recurrent question, but the way I tried to phrase it I did not find  any repeats of it.

I have a data frame that among its columns it has one with date values and other that is a one hot encoding of the presence of an event:

```
date          event
20-11-2019     1
20-11-2019     1
12-3-2018      0
```

I am trying to find a way to obtain the number of events on each of those dates.

I tried to navigate around group by but got nowhere useful. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 2):

Try `groupby` and `sum`

```
out = df.groupby('date',as_index=False).sum()
Out[75]: 
         date  event
0   12-3-2018      0
1  20-11-2019      2
```

Answer (score 0):

does `data.groupby('date')[['event']].sum()` does what you want?