# How to find the total runs for every match (Can be understood by match_id and innings)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
df=pd.read_csv('./ipl/all_matches.csv')
df1=df[['match_id','season','venue','innings','striker','bowler','batting_team','bowling_team','ball','runs_off_bat','extras']]

df1=df1.loc[(df1['ball'] < 6.1)]
df1['total'] = df1['runs_off_bat'] + df1['extras']
```

[image: my dataframe]

[The data frame should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CctDx.jpg)

Comment: you want to group by the match id and sum the runs. have a look at: [pandas groupby and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39922986/13138364)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 0):

Few changes that I've made:

1. Specify the columns that you wanna read in the pd.read_csv args.
2. groupby `match_id` and aggregated the sum of the `total` column for each group.

```
use_col = ['match_id','season','venue','innings','striker','bowler','batting_team','bowling_team','ball','runs_off_bat','extras']
df=pd.read_csv('./ipl/all_matches.csv', usecols= use_col)

df1=df1.loc[(df1['ball'] < 6.1)]
df1['total'] = df1['runs_off_bat'] + df1['extras']
total_run_per_match = df1.groupby('match_id').agg({'total': sum})
```

If you wanna preserve the original data frame:

```
df1['total_run_per_match'] = df1.groupby('match_id')['transform'].sum()
```

Comment: But I want to store that total in that dataframe itself.So how can i do that

Comment: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1 ----the above code generates this error