# Python pandas sum based on unique id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas which has data like the below:

| charge id | charge | payment | adjustment | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | $45 | $30 | 0 | P |
| 123 | $45 | 0 | $10 | A |
| 124 | $50 | $20 | 0 | P |

I then use the pivot table to aggregate the data to produce sums / counts of various fields. However summing the charge is incorrect as the same charge can be in the data multiple times. Is it possible to sum the charge once based on the `charge id` field? So in this example `charge id` `123` would only be included once in the total.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @Shaun, does it work?

Comment: I think the main point here is to avoid duplication calculation of the same figure within a group.  So the link provided (as an attempt of marking as dup) cannot fully answer the question.

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to work with the pivot table function and not have to do anything else with the dataframe, so was looking for an option into the pivot table aggregator to handle this.