# How common one variable is next to another

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble visualising the correlation between one variable and another. My brain is dead on this one.

I have a dataset listing the uptake of a sport across a number of cities based on data from individuals.

So the data looks a bit like:

| Sport | City |
| --- | --- |
| Sport1 | city1 |
| Sport2 | city2 |
| Sport2 | city2 |
| Sport1 | city2 |

What I want to determine is, are certain sports more popular in different cities? ie. from the above we can see that Sport 2 is more popular in City 2. How can I visualise/list this in Python?

Comment: You can use group by and count/sum, possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a pivot table?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sport': ['sport1', 'sport2', 'sport2', 'sport1'],'city': ['city1', 'city2','city2','city2']}
)
df.pivot_table(index='sport',columns='city',aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Output is

|  | city1 | city2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sport1 | 1 | 1 |
| sport2 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: Great output table. Here is alternative code to generate the same output.  `pd.crosstab(df['sport'], df['city'])`