# Python Pandas - check value in two columns, sum the 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which looks similar to this (but 10000 rows instead of 6, and 100 different artists and more genres:

| Year | Genre | Artist | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Classical | Bach | 5 |
| 2019 | Jazz | Beethoven | 6 |
| 2019 | Rock | Mozart | 10 |
| 2020 | Classical | Beethoven | 5 |
| 2019 | Rock | Beethoven | 10 |
| 2020 | Classical | Beethoven | 3 |

Using Pandas I want to create a break down of the total cost, for example for Beethoven:

| Genre | Total Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Classical | 8 |
| Jazz | 6 |
| Rock | 10 |

I know I can have conditional summation using .loc as shown below which works in adding the total cost of classical songs

```
df.loc[df['Genre'] == 'Classical',Cost].sum()
```

So basically, Pandas docs only show examples with a single conditional like I have above and I want to be able to check both the Genre and Artist columns and sum by Genre for each Artist

Comment: sounds like you want [`groupby`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: `df[['Genre', 'Cost']].groupby('Genre').sum()`

Answer (score 1):

What's your expected output? Does

```
df.groupby(['Genre','Artist']).Cost.sum()
```

do what you want?