# How to get sum() for each year and return years and sum of those years in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am using the below code:

```py
df.groupby(['year','value']).sum().groupby(['year','value']).count()
```

And it produces the following table:

```
year  value
1960  5
1962  6
      4
      7
2000  4
2020  7
      3
      9
```

My question is how to get the sum of `value` for each year without using a `for` loop. If it's possible, I presume that `cumsum()` will be the best solution.

Expected result:

```
year  value
1960  5
1962  17
2000  4
2020  19
```

Comment: Can you show an example for `df` before you do any calculations? It would be easier if it were provided in a format that can be copied and pasted directly (as opposed to having to remove the Markdown table syntax by hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = df.groupby('year').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
   year  value
0  1960      5
1  1962     17
2  2000      4
3  2020     19
```

Comment: Thank you user17242583, I just found a similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum