# how to sum values in column based on names reported in another column and report which name does not match the expected target?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to sum calc values for each name and report if = 100.0000?

[image: df example]

output:

name "a" is not 100

[image: output df]

Comment: please don't send images of things that would be necessary on the process of recreating the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Pandas group-by to get sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/how-do-i-pandas-group-by-to-get-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[['name', 'calc']].groupby('name').sum()
```

should give you the sums for each name, should return the output you were looking for

to report which names arent equal to 100, try

```
df1=(df[['name', 'calc']].groupby('name').sum()!=100)

for name in df1.index[df1['calc']==True].to_list():
    print(f'calc of name:{name} does not match target')
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I would like to report the name of for which calc does not match 100.00. Currently my for loop is not working. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: the answer's been edited to include this for you

Comment: Thank you. This is great although it does not fully resolve the issue. I would like to report the sentence " calc of name a does not match target". This is true for all the potential names that there could be for which calc != 100.0
The code above reports a list of names, rather than a sentence with the name for each potential names for which calc !=100.0. What would you modify?

Comment: added a for loop to print your requested string

Comment: Yes! all working perfectly! Thank you :D