# Python sum values in column given a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have 2 column like:

```
Item Code    Units Sold
   179           1
   179           2
   180           1
   180           4
   190           3
   190           5
```

I want to sum up the values in "Units Sold" if they have the same "Item Code" using python and pandas.

Comment: For this input, exactly what should the result be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Pandas group-by to get sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/how-do-i-pandas-group-by-to-get-sum)

Comment: There are thousands of hits on google using your post's title....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use Groupby to do this efficiently

Assuming that the dataframe is df

```
ans = df.groupby(df['Item Code'])['Units Sold'].sum()
```

This is the output .

```
Item Code
179    3
180    5
190    8
Name: Units Sold, dtype: int64
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
Item Code    Units Sold
   179           3
   180           5
   190           8
```

Try this:

```
df.groupby('Item Code')['Units Sold'].sum()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.groupby('Item Code').sum()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```