# Create two columns from the same columns but in different ways

Tags: python

From the table below, I would like to create two columns that aggregate 'amount' depending on the value of 'number' and 'type'.

| number | type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | A | 20 |
| 2 | A | 10 |
| 3 | B | 20 |
| 2 | B | 10 |
| 1 | B | 20 |

Here's the table I would like to get.
The first column I want to create is 'amount A', which is the aggregation of the rows with 'A' in 'type' grouped by 'number'. The other one 'amount A+B' is the aggregation of all the rows grouped by 'number' regardless the value of 'type'.

| number | amount A | amount A+B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 50 |
| 2 | 10 | 20 |
| 3 | 0 | 20 |

I only came up with the way to create subsets and create two columns separately.
But I wonder if there is more efficient way.

Comment: You can check out this thread, maybe this does what you want. Especially the pivot one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/how-do-i-pandas-group-by-to-get-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
out = (
    df.astype({'number': 'category'})
    .query('type == "A"')
    .groupby(['number'])['amount'].sum()
    .to_frame('amount A')
)

out['amount A+B'] = df.groupby('number')['amount'].sum()

print(out)
        amount A  amount A+B
number                      
1             30          50
2             10          20
3              0          20
```

One of the tricks is to convert the `'number'` column to a categorical so that we have a resultant `sum` for all numbers even if a number doesn't appear with `'type A'`.

Once we do that, we can very easily perform a groupby across the numbers with an without the rows where `type == "A"`.