# How to aggregate duplicate rows that have the same geometries?

Tags: python, geopandas

Below is a example of my data set. I want to combine duplicated points  together and get the sum of values in columns a , b  and c into a single row.

I have looked at a previous example using `groupby.sum()` here [How do I Pandas group-by to get sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/how-do-i-pandas-group-by-to-get-sum). Because I am dealing with geometries I can't get my code to work.

| geometry | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| point a | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| point a | 3 | 1 | 7 |
| point b | 1 | 2 | 3 |

This is want I want:

| geometry | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| point a | 5 | 5 | 13 |
| point b | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: Your `geometry` is not geometry in the context of geopandas' capabilities. It is `text string` in the current form.

Comment: If this is actually a geometry, as it seems to be from your question text, then groupby will not work as you note. But please provide a more realistic example, ideally as a [mre] but at least by copying the result of print (df) into the question.

Comment: Frankly, since geometries are not hashable, I don’t know if this is possible using tools available in geopandas. You may be stuck with a horrible double for loop using shapely to compare each shape to all others? But maybe others have ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covert geometry to wtk:

`df = df([df['geometry'].to_wkt()], ).agg('a' : 'sum', 'b' : 'sum', 'c' :'sum').reset_index()`

Then back to geometry:

`df['index'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['index'])`

`df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)`

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'geometry': ['point a', 'point a', 'point b'],
    'a': [2, 3, 1],
    'b': [4, 1, 2],
    'c': [6, 7, 3]})

res = df.groupby('geometry', as_index=False).sum()  

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
  geometry  a  b   c
0  point a  5  5  13
1  point b  1  2   3
```

Comment: The question specifically notes this won’t work since the column contains geometries. These are not hashable and cannot be grouped on.